# How to logout using Expo.Facebook

Tags: react-native, expo

I am using Expo.Facebook.logInWithReadPermissionsAsync.

I have read all the documentation and there is no document on how to logout from Facebook.

Answer (score 2):

In order to logout from Expo.Facebook.logInWithReadPermissionsAsync

Send a fetch with delete to Facebook graphApi:

var lParams= access_token=${token};
fetch(
‘https://graph.facebook.com/User_id/permissions’,{
method : ‘DELETE’,
body: lParams
}

User_id is the user id from Facebook return value. You can get it from
const response = await fetch(
https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=id,name,first_name,last_name,middle_name,picture,email&access_token=${token});
console.log(response);

Answer (score 0):

If somebody wants to remove his profile in the modal window that pops up after You start the `Expo.Facebook`'s login, here is how to do it:

On iOS (simulator or real device):
Go to `Settings > Safari > Clear History and Website data`

On android (tested on real device only):
Go to `Settings > Storage > Other Apps > Chrome > CLEAR STORAGE > CLEAR ALL DATA` (you may tap on "CLEAR CACHE" as well, but the `CLEAR STORAGE` option did the trick for me).

Answer (score -3):

You don't really need to. Just make a state variable like loggedIn when the user is logged in using Facebook Api and reset loggedIn to false when Logout button is clicked.

Comment: This is not enough, when the user tries to log back in using another FB account he won't be able to

Comment: This doesn't helps for loggin with different account.